# Dispatch Group Crash BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Too many nested calls to dispatch_group_enter()

Tags: swift, dispatchgroup

Getting Dispatch Group Crash with Too many nested calls to  dispatch_group_enter(). I double checked the code and there is balance of enter and leave calls. This is happening in Prod for customers. I am not able to reproduce the issue. Can someone help me reproduce the issue or help me with some suggestion on fixing this issue. Got below text in the firebase crash
 `BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Too many nested calls to dispatch_group_enter()`

[dispatch group with data retrival from DB and flushing it to network and after successful call delete the data from DB](https://github.com/sreexamus/KtorSample/blob/master/Sample_Dispatch.txt)

Comment: Show your code. We can't guess without that. But check if in case of error, your completion still call `leave()`. Etc.

Comment: @Larme thanks for reply! error is about too many group enters. Do you know why we get this error?

Comment: @Larme i have provided link with code

Comment: The only way you can get this error is if `enter` calls are unbalanced with `leave` calls. I know you don’t think this is happening, but that has to be what’s going on. Perhaps one or more of your `persistenceManager` methods is failing to call its closure. Maybe keep your own counter, incremented at `enter` and decremented at `leave` and confirm.